# Redo command doesn't work

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

***Undo*** command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) works fine, but ***Redo*** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) doesn't work for me anymore. How to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for tip @MrZak. I know the 'undo history' shortcut, but Ctrl+Shift+Z was much faster. In previous Blender version it worked well. It's super strange it doesn't now :(.

Comment: I meant probably this problem could be quickly fixed by using Undo history. It's strange indeed if it persists (a bug?); you could try to recreate it with default file and post either here or on bug tracker.

Comment: [Related question.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12216/why-do-only-some-tools-have-redo-capability) TL;DR: Some types of edits have been deemed unworthy of redo functionality because they rely on the 3D Viewport perspective and/or 3D Cursor position. :-(

Comment: Deemed unworthy? This is the 3rd time in a row this week I destroy 2 hours of work becuase of a Ctrl-Z that I pushed in Object Mode instead of in Edit Mode. I'm about to snap.

Comment: Is the bug fixed yet?