# Blender autosave

Tags: workflow

Some actions deemed "unworthy" [cannot be redone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12216/why-do-only-some-tools-have-redo-capability) with Ctrl + Shift + Z since apparently it wouldn't make sense. However when you Ctrl + Z past such an action (easily done if you accidentally Ctrl + Z in Object Mode instead of in Edit Mode) you cannot redo all the work you have done after performing an "unworthy" action which causes tremendous loss of work every so often.

Besides that, the power could go out, or the computer could freeze.

Is there any way I can force blender to autosave every 30 seconds into a new blend file so I don't get these urges anymore to close blender, shut down my computer, go outside and murder somebody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a auto save feature in blender by default.

"File" -> "Recover Auto Save ..." would show you the tmp folder where the last file were saved, you can load it from there.

You can set the interval to save the file, in "File" -> "User Preferences ..." -> "File" tab -> see "Auto Save Temporary Files" option.
Also you can set the "Temp:" file location, where the file is saved.
As for me in OSX it save only one file with the same name as the file.

You can use other external options to save that file at given intervals for more backups.