# Where are .blend files saved?

Tags: blend-files, saving

I have looked everywhere on my computer, and I cannot find where the .blend files are saved. I try to Google this question, but I only get results for removing textures.

Answer (score 2):

Blend files are saved where-ever you chose to save them, opening Blender trying to save again will show the default location.

Blender also has an autosave function that saves backup files to a temporary directory, see [Blender autosave](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82577/blender-autosave)